# Is there a way to require a login when accessing a website run on Google Cloud?

Tags: .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, .htpasswd

I'm currently making a website using a VM instance on Google Cloud. I've tried to password-protect my website using .htaccess and .htpass so that people cannot access it until I have completed it, but I will still be able to see it (because I have the login). However, .htaccess and .htpass don't seem to be working, and I'm unsure if there's something wrong on my side or if they simply do not work on GCloud VM instances. If they do not work on GCloud instances, are there any alternatives?

Comment: "are there any alternatives?" - If you have a (relatively) static IP address then you can permit just your IP address and block everyone else (also less annoying than a user/pwd dialog).

Comment: Google Cloud Compute Engine instances do not affect web server authentication methods. That is entirely up to you to correctly configure your web server. There are of course much better methods such as OAuth 2. What you are trying to do is very basic. There are lots of examples and documents on the Internet. https://www.ryadel.com/en/user-authentication-authorization-web-development-login-auth-identity/

Comment: Can you host your website on App Engine? At least, is it possible to containerize it and to run it on App Engine Flex?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Apache web server you need to enable the use of htaccess on the Apache configuration. Check these guides as references [How To Enable & Set Up .htaccess File On Apache](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-set-up-enable-htaccess-apache), [How To Use the .htaccess File](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file). Keep in mind the path of the Apache config file can be different, depends on which Linux distro or Windows OS are using.